# Get-PnPListItem exceeds the lookup column threshold

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, pnp-powershell

We are having some issues querying some lists and libraries and I'm afraid we have stared ourselves blind on the matter.

We run the following cmdlet and it throws an error:

```
$listItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $list -Query $query -IncludeContentType
```

```
Reporting on list failed. Error: System.Management.Automation.PSInvalidOperationException: The query cannot be completed because the number of lookup columns it contains exceeds the lookup column threshold.
   at PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.PnPConnectedCmdlet.ProcessRecord() in c:\build\src\Commands\Base\PnPConnectedCmdlet.cs:line 101
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
```

The query contains the following viewfields where all non-system viewfields are managed metadata fields.

```xml
 <View>
       <ViewFields>
            <FieldRef Name='Title' />
            <FieldRef Name='Created' />
            <FieldRef Name='Modified' />
            <FieldRef Name='Author' />
            <FieldRef Name='Editor' />
            <FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId' />
            <FieldRef Name='FileRef' />
            <FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' />
            <FieldRef Name='Practices' />
            <FieldRef Name='TaxKeyword' />
            <FieldRef Name='fltrDirLocations_Dyn' />
            <FieldRef Name='Page_x0020_owner_x0028_s_x0029_' />
            <FieldRef Name='Business_x0020_services' />
            <FieldRef Name='Categories_x0020__x0028_subject_x0029_' />
            <FieldRef Name='Industry_x0020_sector_x0028_s_x0029_' />
            <FieldRef Name='Countries' />
            <FieldRef Name='DocumentType' />
            <FieldRef Name='Author_x0028_s_x0029_' />
       </ViewFields>    
</View>
```

Since Author and Editor are people fields they count towards the lookup column threshold of 12.

However, since we're not exceeding the limit I don't understand why we're seeing an error suggesting we are past this limit?

We've tried to strip away everything aside from all non-system viewfields, author and editor. This gives us 12 fields in total, but it still fails.

```xml
 <View>
       <ViewFields>
            <FieldRef Name='Author' />
            <FieldRef Name='Editor' />
            <FieldRef Name='Practices' />
            <FieldRef Name='TaxKeyword' />
            <FieldRef Name='fltrDirLocations_Dyn' />
            <FieldRef Name='Page_x0020_owner_x0028_s_x0029_' />
            <FieldRef Name='Business_x0020_services' />
            <FieldRef Name='Categories_x0020__x0028_subject_x0029_' />
            <FieldRef Name='Industry_x0020_sector_x0028_s_x0029_' />
            <FieldRef Name='Countries' />
            <FieldRef Name='DocumentType' />
            <FieldRef Name='Author_x0028_s_x0029_' />
       </ViewFields>    
</View>
```

We tried removing the `-IncludeContentType` from `Get-PnPListITem`, but it still fails.

If we strip away one additional viewfield such as Author, then it will work as intended.

Any idea about what the issue could be or what to look for next?

Comment: How many total items are there in the list? Try adding indexing on fields you are trying to retrieve (you can add up to 20 indices): https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-an-index-to-a-list-or-library-column-f3f00554-b7dc-44d1-a2ed-d477eac463b0. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: One of the sites in question we have one item in a document library and 146 items in the site page library. You still think adding indexes can make a difference for the error message "The query cannot be completed because the number of lookup columns it contains exceeds the lookup column threshold."?